# Deploy from octopus to azure gives connection error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, octopus-deploy, azure-webapps

I deploy my asp.net core app from octopus (v2018.8.12) to azure. And after update app from .NET Core 1.1 to 2.1 deploy stopped to work and i get this exception:

> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Web Deploy
>   experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate
>   the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem
>   persists.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
>   ---> System.Xml.XmlException: There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1, position 84.

Deploy from visual studio still works. Also deploying of another apps works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreation of whole web app helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the cause was that TCP port 8172 needed by webdeploy (which is used under the covers by Octopus Deploy and Azure App Service) was being blocked by a outbound firewall from my deployment machine. Opening the port fixed the issue, Or you can swap to use [ZipDeploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip#rest) and a powershell script